# Centering list <div> in page

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I can't seem to center this list element in the page. It contains three equally-sized boxes, and I'd like them to always stick to the center.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
}

.boxes {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.all {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box1 all"></div>
        <div class="box2 all"></div>
        <div class="box3 all"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `margin: auto` to work, your elements need to have a width given to them somehow (usually through `width`). The usual solution to make things scale automatically is `display: inline-block;` (though flexbox makes this *much* easier when supported):

```css
.box-container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Then you’d give its parent `text-align: center;`. Alternatively, `width: 300px;` (with perhaps a minor adjustment or removal of spaces) seems like it could work well here; it depends on your actual layout.

`body` doesn’t need `width: 100%;`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For everything you want to center horizontally, you should set its margin-left and margin-right to 'auto'.

Comment: That part where it says `margin: 0 auto;` should do that…

Comment: That will center .box-container not the smaller boxes. You have re-set the margins of the boxes within the .all class to a fixed 10px.

Answer (score 0):

Give your box container a width:

CSS

```
.box-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 360px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/82WCU/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: right` from each the `all` class. That is causing the boxes to move to the right. Make the `box-container` center aligned (this will bring them to the center), and change the display of each box to `inline-block`.

```
 .box-container {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .all {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
     margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.box-container {
    text-align:center;
}
.all {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

NOTE:

`inline-block` leaves white-space between elements. To remove this space, write elements on same line rather than writing them on separate lines.

Change:

to

```
<div class="box-container">
        <div class="box1 all"></div><div class="box2 all"></div><div class="box3 all"></div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2HbAU/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This it work perfectly:**

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box1 all"></div>
        <div class="box2 all"></div>
        <div class="box3 all"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}

.boxes {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.all {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 13%;
    width: 100px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```